# Can anyone explain me this quicksort example?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I watched a video about quick sort, but I don't understand the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int left = 0;
    int right = array.length - 1;

    for (left = 0; left < right; left++, right--) {
        int temp = array[left];
        array[left] = array[right];
        array[right] = temp;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}
```

This part is what confuses me:

```
int temp = array[left];
array[left] = array[right];
array[right] = temp;
```

Can you please explain it to me?

Comment: it's just swapping elements at specified indexes.

Comment: It's a way to swap the elements in the array.  The `temp` variable is an intermediate placeholder to store `array[left]` value for the interchange of left to right.

Comment: That's not even quicksort. It just reverses the array.

Comment: I think you need to find a new video, because that code ain't quick sort.

Comment: Write down the whole algorithm on paper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet swaps the values of `array[left]` and `array[right]`, nothing more.

---

It does so by first **memorizing** the value of `array[left]` in a temporary variable `temp` because it soon gets overridden.

After that it **overrides** the value at `array[left]` with the value stored in `array[right]`.

Finally it writes the **memorized value** of the old `array[left]`, stored in `temp`, to `array[right]`.

---

Here is a small illustration of the process:

[image: Illustration]